# Is it worth comparing value before exchange in terms of speed?

Tags: c++, performance, pointers, null, compare

The title may sound complicated but it will be very easy to understand after few lines of code.

Lets say you have an array of pointers, which may be NULL or may point to actual structures. Our task is to set all the pointers to NULL (deletion doesn't matter).

We can do it the following ways:

```
 // first way
 array[i] = NULL;

 // second way
 if (array[i] != NULL)
      array[i] = NULL;
```

I wonder, if we did it the second way, would we save some speed on values that already were NULL? Let's say array is 50% NULL already. My university lecturer once mentioned that "comparing doesn't cost much, while value changing does". Is it true? Would we have any positive impact on speed if we did it the second way? Or the additional comparison would only waste time?

Comment: IMHO you're better off leaving the branch out.  It may be cheap, but if the CPU branch predictor gets it wrong, then that's expensive.  Just do the assignments, assigning a NULL to a NULL will not cost you anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First way is always faster. You have to read the pointer to check that it's null, then write it, which takes longer than just writing it. Whilst doing the compare itself may not take much time, the consequences of taking a conditional branch is definitely not good. [Ok, so the compiler MAY eliminate it, but not at all guaranteed].

But as always with performance, "Asking on the internet is not a replacement for measurement!".

Comment: If you have entire memory pages full of NULLs, avoiding the store instruction can limit the number of cache line invalidations. So in some very particular cases, it may worth testing before erasing. I agree that in most case, it isn't worth.

Comment: Yes, if you can avoid a whole cache-line at a time, perhaps. But that would be in a SMP system where other processors have read the same data, in which case we also would have care about locking and a whole lot of other issues.

Answer (score 2):

If we could always save something doing that the compiler would do this mechanical transformation in a lot of cases. Never heard about it.

I can think of **at least one** situation where it might save something: If you have a huge array that you assign to at random locations and the value is often the same. In that case you probably want to expend the cycles for the branch in order to save the CPU from dirtying the cache line and being forced to write it back.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "it depends", as usual.  On how big your problem set is, and the characteristics of your particular machine.  Nothing beats profiling for *actual empirical evidence*.

You're essentially trading one of these for the other:

- The cost of conditional branching.
- The cost of memory access.

Your first solution requires, for each array element, only a memory write.  The second solution requires a read, compare, and then a conditional write.  If reads are cheaper than writes, and comparisons relatively cheap, then it could be faster if there are many NULL entries.

My top-of-my-head answer is that the first method, which amounts to a `memcpy`, is probably faster on modern processors, especially if optimized with non-temporal writes, since it does not branch (expensive!) and needs not trash your CPU cache with elements only read once.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the basic principle: what your instructor told you is often exactly backwards. A write is typically faster than a read. Specifically (at least with most modern CPUs) a write just means depositing an address and value into a queue. Other parts of the CPU can then handle writing that value out to memory, while the execution units can get on with executing more instructions. The instruction stream can stall, however, if you try to write more data when/if the write queues are already full.

By contrast, to do a comparison, if the data isn't already in the cache, it has to write the address out to memory, and then stall until the data arrives from memory to be able to use it for the comparison proper.

Comparisons also use the flags register, which have a great deal of "register pressure" because most instructions modify them. This can prevent instruction level parallelism that would otherwise be available.

Now, it is true that you'd generally rather avoid polluting the cache with the data in question unless you're going to be using it for some other purpose soon. Some caches avoid this entirely by *not* allocating cache space on writes -- i.e., unless you've read data recently so it's already in the cache, writing to it won't move it into the cache; it'll just write the data directly to main memory.

Many (most?) recent processors also feature instructions that always write directly to memory, regardless of caching policy. Intel (for example) calls these non-temporal stores (e.g., MOVNTQ and MOVNTPS). These can be a little tricky to use correctly though. Unlike a normal memory write, they do not guarantee cache coherency by default. You need to execute an SFENCE instruction after the writes to ensure that other processors will see the result of the writing.

The other time it would be worth doing a comparison would be when a single comparison allowed you to avoid a *lot* of writes. Just for example, let's assume your array was quite sparse, so only around one out of a few hundred entries was non-null. In such a case, you could (for one example) use a bitmap where one bit in the bitmap said whether a pointer was null or not. In a case like this, a single 64-bit comparison could let you avoid (for example) writing to *any* of 64 different pointers of 64 bits each.

Looking at the pointers individually won't give an advantage though -- to be specific, you'll need to load each pointer into the cache before you can do the comparison, so attempting to compare one by one to avoid polluting the cache is a self-defeating proposition.